# Java: Issue with Using Scanner object and object's close function

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

Did this for a java class I am taking. Its supposed to generate some random index and ask you for a new integer to place at that index of the array.

There is a weird issue with using console.close() at the end of the ChangeOne() method. I know its standard to close a Scanner instance when you are finished with it, so I don't get why in this case that is not applicable:

```
import java.util.*;
public class ChangeUp {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int[] list = new int[6];
    printArray(list);
    for (int x=0; x<6; x++)
    {
        changeOne(list);
        printArray(list);
    }
}
public static void printArray(int[] somearray)
{
    int arraylen = somearray.length;
    for(int j=0; j < arraylen; j++)
    {
        System.out.println("Value: " + somearray[j]);
    }
}
public static void changeOne(int[] somearray)
{
    int arraylen = somearray.length;
    Random r = new Random();
    int index = r.nextInt(arraylen);
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.printf("The chosen index equals %d. Enter a new integer for that index: \n", index);
    while ( !console.hasNextInt())
    {
        console.next();
        System.out.printf("The chosen index equals %d. Enter a new integer for that index: \n", index);
    }
    int v = console.nextInt();
    somearray[index] = v;
    console.close();

}
}
```

Comment: what is the exact issue/error?

Comment: When you close a `Scanner(System.in)` JVM also closes its underlying stream. It means once you close such Scanner you will not be able to open it again in the same program.